# Vertical List view of cards- incorrect cards getting opened

Tags: android, android-listview

We have created a vertical list view of news cards in the scroller which 
is working fine, but when we open any card in the list - for example the
5th card in the scroller - it always open the 1st card.

So be it any number of card you further try to open up it always opens first card only. I am unable to catch error for it as i am novice into android development.

Could you please help?

Following is the adapter code we have in place. Would be very grateful if you can help in fixing this bug

```
package messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.ScrollView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.Activity.News;
import messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.Activity.NewsBrowser;
import messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.Model.ArticleResponse;
import messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.Model.NewsUrl;
import messenger.fb.video.chat.lite.message.R;

public class VerticlePagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
    private ImageView newsImage;
    private ArticleResponse articleResponse;
    private NewsUrl newsBrowser;
    private TextView title, description, source,times,readFullStory;
    private List<ArticleResponse> articleResponseList;
    private Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
    private int position;
    private int count = 0;

    public VerticlePagerAdapter(Context context, List<ArticleResponse> articleResponseList, int position) {
        this.context = context;
        this.articleResponseList = articleResponseList;
        this.position = position;
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return articleResponseList.size();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
        return view == ((LinearLayout)o);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        View itemView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.top_stories_single_news_layout, container, false);
        newsImage = (ImageView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsImage);
        title = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTitle);
        description = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.description);
        source = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.source);
        times = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.newsTime);
        readFullStory = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.read_full_story);
            articleResponse = articleResponseList.get(position);
            newsBrowser = new NewsUrl(articleResponse.getArticleSourceResponses().getName(), articleResponse.getUrl());
            Glide.with(context)
                    .load(articleResponse.getUrlToImage())
                    .into(newsImage);
            title.setText(articleResponse.getTitle());
            source.setText(articleResponse.getArticleSourceResponses().getName() + " | ");
            SimpleDateFormat input = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");
            SimpleDateFormat output = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss");
            Date d = null;
            Date time = new Date();
            try {
                d = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'").parse(articleResponse.getPublishedAt());
                time = input.parse(time.toString());
            } catch (ParseException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            long diff = time.getTime() - d.getTime();
            Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
            cal.setTimeInMillis(diff);
            String publishedTime = "";
            if (cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) > 0)
                publishedTime = publishedTime + cal.get(Calendar.HOUR) + " hours, ";
            if (cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) > 0)
                publishedTime = publishedTime + cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE) + " minutes ago";
            else
                publishedTime = publishedTime + " ago";
            times.setText(publishedTime);
            description.setText(articleResponse.getDescription());
            readFullStory.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent browserIntent = new Intent(context, NewsBrowser.class);
                    browserIntent.putExtra("url", newsBrowser);
                    context.startActivity(browserIntent);
                }
            });
               // container.addView(itemView);
        return itemView;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
            container.removeView((LinearLayout) object);
    }
}
```

Comment: Try renaming your position variable in the class to something else it may be a conflict between the position variable for the class with the position variable of the function

Comment: It looks ok at first glance. I would log the ArticleResponse items each time instantiateItem is called so you can check if the urls are as expected.

Comment: Thanks people.. let me try implementing these suggestions and come back